2 requests to SharePoint Rest APi (Get & Post) inside a Batch request inside Power Automate. Get the result of the Get and send it inside the Post
Currently i am doing those 2 actions inside my Flow:-

Get the Info of a group mainly the PrincipleID using the group name

Pass the PrincipleID of the group in another POST request to Assign a permission for the group to a list item



Now I want to join the 2 requests into one request inside a Batch, Here is the Body of the Batch request I am planning to use:-

Here is the Batch request Body:-
--batch_1234
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_1234"

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/_api/web/SiteUsers/GetByLoginName('*****')/Id HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/_api/web/lists(****)/items(***)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=**GET THE RESULT OF THE GET REQUEST**?['d']?['Id']},roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234--
--batch_1234--

But the question is how i can get the ID from the output of the Get request and pass it to the Post request inside the same Batch request Body??
Thanks

I suggest you run this one passed ChatGPT.

@Skin thanks for your reply, did not get your point.

The documentation of Batch Processing (OData Version 3.0) explains this scenario: 2.2.1 Referencing Requests in a Change Set.
You have to add something like Content-ID: 1 in the header of the first request, and use the value of the response as $1 in the next request.
Your code should probably be changed to that (I let you test and comment the final answer here, and, as @Skin mentioned in the comment, you can ask for more sample with ChatGPT):
--batch_1234
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_1234"

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 42

GET https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/_api/web/SiteUsers/GetByLoginName('*****')/Id HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/_api/web/lists(****)/items(***)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=$42,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234--
--batch_1234--


have you tried this? Because Power Automate will pass the PrincipleId=$42 as-is and not the actual Id that get returned from the first Get .. not sure how i can inform power automate that we need the value of the $42 and not the text as-is ??

No, I didn't test it (I let you test). I think it's better to use batch requests with independent requests. But the technology behind bulk request allows to reference previous request. Good luck, but it's definitely possible!
